# Fluentd seems to be working but no logs in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluentd

I have a Kubernetes pod consisting of two containers - main app (writes logs to file on volume) and Fluentd sidecar that tails log file and writes to Elasticsearch.

Here is the Fluentd configuration:

```
<source>
  type tail
  format none
  path /test/log/system.log
  pos_file /test/log/system.log.pos
  tag anm
</source>

<match **>
  @id elasticsearch
  @type elasticsearch
  @log_level debug
  time_key @timestamp
  include_timestamp true
  include_tag_key true
  host elasticsearch-logging.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
  port 9200
  logstash_format true
  <buffer>
    @type file
    path /var/log/fluentd-buffers/kubernetes.system.buffer
    flush_mode interval
    retry_type exponential_backoff
    flush_thread_count 2
    flush_interval 5s
    retry_forever
    retry_max_interval 30
    chunk_limit_size 2M
    queue_limit_length 8
    overflow_action block
  </buffer>
</match>
```

Everything is working, Elasticsearch host & port are correct since API works correctly on that URL. In Kibana I see only records every 5 seconds about Fluentd creating new chunk:

```
2018-12-03 12:15:50 +0000 [debug]: #0 [elasticsearch] Created new chunk chunk_id="57c1d1c105bcc60d2e2e671dfa5bef04" metadata=#<struct Fluent::Plugin::Buffer::Metadata timekey=nil, tag="anm", variables=nil>
```

but no actual logs in Kibana (the ones that are being written by the app to system.log file). Kibana is configured to the "logstash-*" index pattern that matches the one and only existing index.

Version of Fluentd image: k8s.gcr.io/fluentd-elasticsearch:v2.0.4

Version of Elasticsearch: k8s.gcr.io/elasticsearch:v6.3.0

Where can I check to find out what's wrong? Looks like Fluentd does not get to put the logs into Elasticsearch, but what can be the reason?

Comment: Please provide a Deployment or Pod spec.

Comment: You may want to check if there are really logs in /test/log/system.log based on your fluentd side car config.

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to be embarrassingly simple, maybe will help someone in the future.

I figured the problem was with this source config line:

```
<source>
...
    format none
...
</source>
```

That meant that no usual tags where added when saved to elasticsearch (e.g. pod or container name) and I had to search for these records in Kibana in a completely different way. For instance, I used my own tag to search for those records and found them alright. The custom tag was originally added just in case, but turned out to be very useful:

```
<source>
...
    tag anm
...
</source>
```

So, the final takeaway could be the following. Use "format none" with caution, and if the source data actually is unstructured, add your own tags, and possibly enrich with additional tags/info (e.g. "hostname", etc) using fluentd's [record_transformer](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/filter_record_transformer), which I ended up also doing. Then it will be much easier to locate the records via Kibana.